# op amps comparator or differential amplifier

Tags: operational-amplifier, current-source, differential, comparator

I have a part of electronic schematic as described bellow, I'm a little bit confusing about the function of the LM321 amplifier. In this case, can we say that is a differential amplifier or just a comparator (open loop, no feedback, cause of the PNP transistor)?
[image]

I thank you for your support.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to remove the shouting from the title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you see an opamp circuit and ask yourself is this **open loop / a comparator** or not?

Then first see if there is feedback.

If there is no connection back to the input(s) then it is a comparator:

[image]

[Source](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/opamp/op-amp-comparator.html)

If there **is** feedback it can still be a comparator (possibly with hysteresis) but it can also be a **linear amplifier**.

Now check if the feedback is **positive** (feed forward) or **negative** (feed back).

Here's an example of a comparator with positive feedback meaning it has hysteresis:

[image]

Note how the signal going back goes to the **+ (positive) input** of the opamp.

This is an example of **negative** feedback so this is a linear amplifier:

[image]

Note how the signal going back goes to the **- (negative) input** of the opamp.

In your circuit there is a PNP transistor in series with the feedback. (Next time, draw transistors with the arrow pointing down as that indicates the direction of the current flow which is from the positive supply **down** to ground.) This PNP is in a **common collector configuration** also called **emitter follower**. A property of that configuration is that it **does not invert the signal** (which common configuration does invert the signal?) so that means that the feedback isn't inverted and since the signal feeds back to the - input of the opamp, this is a **linear amplifier** circuit.

That means that the opamp will try (and when the circuit is dimensioned well, the opamp will succeed) and make the voltages at its + and - inputs **the same**. That means that the voltage across zener diode D1 is **copied** across Resistor R2.

I would draw the circuit like this as that makes it easier to understand:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fItLmz.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The result of that constant voltage across R2 is that the **current** through R2 will be **constant** as well. That constant current flows through Q1 into R3 which is the load. You can change the value of R3 (within practical limits) but the current through R3 would remain constant. This circuit is called a **current source** or **current reference**.

Comment: How do you make sure the comparator doesn't oscillate given that it doesn't have an internal compensation capacitor?

Comment: Bimpelrekkie: Thanks for your detailed explanation. However I didn't understand how the Voltage across VIN+ is equal to the voltage across D1 ? I have always thought that the Voltage across VIN+ for such schematic is equal to the voltage across R1.

Comment: You have to make a difference between "voltage across" and "voltage". For a "voltage across" you obviously need **two points**, for D1 that is the 25.2 V line and the 19 V at the + input of the opamp, then the "voltage across" is 25.2 V - 19 V = 6.2 V. You're talking about "voltage" and only mention VIN+, that means we talk about the voltage between that point (VIN+) and **GROUND**, here that's 19 V. So yes, VIN+ is 19 V.  That's the **potential**.

Comment: But this circuit isn't standard as it is **referenced to the positive supply rail**. That means it makes a constant voltage (of 6.2 V) lower than the supply rail of 25.2 V. Imagine what happens when the supply increases to 27.2 V. Does the 19 V stay 19 V? Does the voltage across D1 change? What happens to the voltage across R2?

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie: Indeed, the voltage will increase with an amount of 2V. So, it will be equal to 21V. However, the voltage at the VIN+ will still equal to 6V2. Is that true ?

Comment: *the voltage at the VIN+ will still equal to 6V2. Is that true ?* NO, the **voltage across D1** stays 6.2 V. You're still confusing potential voltage (always referenced to ground) and voltage **across** a component. So: VIN+ changes form 19 V to 21 V. The voltage **across** D1 doesn't change and stays 6.2 V.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie: The voltage across the diode never change, but the voltage across R1 will increase with an amount of 2V if we increase the supply to 27.2 instead of 25.2V. So the voltage across R1 will be equal to 21V. My confusing is about VIN+ and the juste voltage "in one point"

Comment: Exactly, make a difference between "voltage across X" (between two points, none of which is ground) and the "voltage at Y" (voltage at a point relative to ground).

Answer (score 1):

The op-amp has negative feedback from the emitter of the PNP transistor and therefore it seeks to ensure that the voltage across R2 is the same as the voltage across zener diode D1 (note that V1 = V2 = V3). Simplified: -

[image]

Comment: Thanks Andy for your answer, but I didn't understand ur explanation, how it can get equal voltage between D1 and R2 ? Can you explain to me more ? Thanks.

Comment: @geek225 the op-amp (due to negative feedback) seeks to ensure that its two input terminals have the same voltage. It can't do anything to alter the voltage on the non-inverting input because that is set by the zener diode but, it can do something to ensure that the voltage at the inverting terminal matches the non-inverting terminal and this is what it does; it will raise or lower its output voltage to make the emitter voltage the same as the voltage on the non-inverting input. Given that Vcc is shared this means V(D1) = V(R2).

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I have one more question about this circuit, which formula I have to consider to determine the gain for this amplifier (Vout/Vin) ? Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 1):

A sophisticated technique for explaining circuits is to build them step by step by adding the next element only after you have clarified the need for it. I have demonstrated it below by a 5-step building scenario. It is illustrated by gradually growing circuit diagrams.

As usual, I have visualized the invisible voltages and drops by bars (in red) with proportional heights… and the currents with loops (in green). Here is my story...

**1. Zener voltage stabilizer unloaded.** To obtain reference voltage, we connect a resistor R1 in series to a Zener diode D1. Since, in the OP's circuit, the voltage is referenced to V+, the diode is above the resistor. This voltage stabilizer works at ideal load conditions (open circuit); so the voltage across the diode (output voltage) is stable.

[image: Zener voltage stabilizer unloaded]

**2. Loading the stabilizer.** But we have created this stabilizer with the purpose somehow to use its voltage. So, we connect a load (e.g., a resistor R2) in parallel to the Zener diode. But it diverts a part IL of the current ID through the diode and its voltage slightly decreases. The problem will be even bigger if we vary R2.

[image: Zener voltage stabilizer loaded]

**3. Adding a transistor buffer.** Obviously, we have somehow to decrease the current diverted from the Zener diode… but still to keep the same current IL through the load. For this purpose, we have to connect a *voltage buffer* between the Zener stabilizer and the load, e.g., a transistor Q1 acting as an *emitter follower*. By passing the big current IL through R2, it copies the Zener voltage across R2… and only the small base current is diverted from the Zener diode. The transistor does this "magic" (aka "negative feedback") by comparing its base and emitter voltage and changing the current until it reaches the equilibrium.

[image: Zener voltage stabilizer with transistor buffer]

But another problem appears - the voltage drop VBE (about 0.7 V) across the base-emitter junction, that decreases the load voltage. How do we solve it?

**4. Adding an op-amp buffer.** Maybe the ubiquitous op-amp will help us? We decide to connect another but perfect op-amp voltage follower (OA1) before the imperfect emitter  follower. Now the op-amp does the "magic" of the negative feedback by comparing the voltages of its non-inverting and inverting inputs until V(-) = V(+) that means V(-) = VOA = VD1.

[image: Zener voltage stabilizer with op-amp buffer]

The op-amp will do, we think, a precise "voltage copy"... while the transistor will provide the big load current. Yes, it does make an exact voltage copy… but at its output and transistor base. We need to see this copy at the emitter… across R2. We have to change something to make the op-amp keep the emitter (not the base voltage) equal to the Zener voltage.

**5. Putting the transistor in the feedback loop.** So we disconnect the inverting input from the base and connect it to the emitter. Now the op-amp changes the base voltage and observes the emitter voltage until it becomes equal to the reference voltage VD1.

[image: Zener voltage stabilizer with smart op-amp buffer]

Thus the op-amp lowers its output voltage with additional VBE voltage (about 0.7 V) and compensates the voltage drop VBE across the base-emitter junction. As a result, VR2 = VD1, and we can think of the combination of op-amp and transistor as of an "ideal transistor" without VBE (in yellow).

**6. What is the output?** It is time to reveal the role of resistor R3. In fact, there are two outputs in this circuit - VR2 and VR3, and we can connect the load in the place of R2… R3… or both… but there is a significant difference in these applications.

If R2 is the load, then the voltage across VR2 (out 1) will be constant and will not depend on the resistance.

If R3 is the load, then the current through it will be constant and almost equal to the current through R2… and will not depend on the resistance R2. But the voltage VR3 (out 2) will depend on the resistance...

---

I hope you enjoyed this constructive way of looking at this circuit and you will apply it to other circuits as well.